# Can we push a Custom Type Object on Stack Operand in BCEL?

Tags: java, bytecode, bcel

*In BCEL we can push primitive types on Operand Stack*. BUT now I want to know if it is possible to **push a Custom Type Object on Stack** in BCEL?

I am giving some code so that it can explain the Problem Context

```
    class Automobile {

public void getEngine(int carNo,EngineClass engineClassObj){

System.out.println("EngineNo="+engineClassObj.sisNo);
}
}

Now when i load "Automobile" class in memory.

ilist = new InstructionList();
ilist.append(InstructionConstants.ALOAD_0);
ilist.append(new PUSH(pgen,345));

////Hear Now i have to also push the Object on Stack

ilist.append(ifact.createInvoke(_invoking_ClassName,_invoking_MethodName, Type.INT,*
new Type[] { Type.INT,Type.OBJECT }, Constants.INVOKEVIRTUAL));

ilist.append(InstructionConstants.IRETURN);
```

1-if i use createNew() method and generate new object then how i am going to 
fill its fields value?
2-or if i firstly push all fields values of Engine type Obj on Stack using PUSH 
then i can some how construct object on memory & then push it on Stack.
these are some solution i can think of.

But i don't know the right solution 
So Still need help ...

Comment: What do you mean by custom object? A reference to some object?

Comment: @aioobe, i have add the code of snippet hope u get it now

Answer (score 1):

[NEW](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/NEW.html) creates a new object and places a reference to it on stack. It needs an index to the  class reference in the constant pool which can be obtained with [ConstantPoolGen.addClass](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/ConstantPoolGen.html#addClass%28java.lang.String%29). For example:

```
il = new InstructionList();
il.append(new NEW(cp.addClass("java.lang.StringBuffer")));
```

This is taken from [ASTProgram.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jakarta/bcel/trunk/src/examples/Mini/ASTProgram.java) which is a part of BCEL examples.

There are other ways to get an object reference on stack as well. For example, [ACONST_NULL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/ACONST_NULL.html) pushes a null reference on stack, [ALOAD](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/ALOAD.html) loads a reference from local variable or [GETSTATIC](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/GETSTATIC.html) fetches static field from class.

Comment: when i use ALoad _0 then it will gave this exception::Unable to pop operand off an empty stack.This will point out that we need to push some thing on Stack. in case of load it what do u say abt it!

Comment: @zaree: Reference to what object do you want to put on stack? If it is a null reference use ACONST_NULL. Otherwise it should come from somewhere, for example, from a local variable in which case use ALOAD with an index of local variable. Or you can create an object using NEW.

Comment: can u elaborate your ans within any example

Comment: @zaree: Sure. I've added an example of using NEW.